# Why the next set is not open?

Tags: general-topology

I hope you can help me with my next question.

Let U be a subset of a continuum X (that is, it is a connected, compact, metric space).
And let's consider the set $2^{X} = \{ U \subset X:$ U is closed and not empty$\}$.
I'm using hausdorff metric $H(A,B)= \inf \{ \epsilon>0: A \subset N(\epsilon,B)$ and  $B \subset N(\epsilon,A) \}$ for $2^{X}$, where $N(\epsilon,A)=\{x \in X:$ exists $a \in A$ such that $d(a,x)< \epsilon \}$. Note that $ N (\epsilon, A) = \cup_{a \in A} B_{d}(\epsilon, a)$ so it is an open at $ X $.

I prove that if $ U $ be an open and nonempty subset of $ X $ then the set defined by
$ C(U) = \{B \in 2^{X}: B \subset U \} $
is open of $2^{X}$.

Proof:

Let $ B \in C(U) $. By definition $ B \subset U $. And  there exists $ \delta > 0 $ such that $ N (\delta, B) \subset U $. It will now be shown that $ B_{H} (\delta, B) \subset C(U) $.

Let $ C \in B_{H}(\delta, B) $. Since $ H (C, B) < \delta $ then $ C \subset N(\delta, B) \subset U $ so $ C \in C(U) $. With this we have that given an element $ B \in C(U) $, there exists the open $ B_{H} (\delta, B) $ of $ 2^{X} $ such that $ B_{H}(\delta, B) \subset C(U) $, so  C(U) is an open at $ 2^{X} $.

My doubt is why the set $E(U)=\{B \in 2^{X}: U \subset B\}$ (where U is open)  is not open in $2^{X}$.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews he said he's using the Hausdorff metric (which induces a topology like any metric does).

Comment: So the question is only "is $E(U)$ open in $2^X$ or not"?

Comment: For that question you need a concrete counterexample then...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hausdorff metric section was added after my comment.

Comment: $$E(U)$ is closed in $2^X$ and nontrivial if $U \neq \emptyset$ so by connectedness of $2^X$ it’s never open in that case.